# transitive implicits - is this possible in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, implicit

Let's say I have several functions:

```
func1 : A => B

func2:  B => C

func3:  C => D
```

I would like to orchestrate now functions when needed in a generic fashion.

let's say if i need a conversion from `A` to `B` I'd call `func1`.
But when I need a conversion from `A` to `D` I would like to have a composition of those functions. Is such thing possible in a dynamic notion?

Comment: Considering implicits already kill compile time and reduce the overall readability of your project and thus reduce the overall productivity when working on it, what you want sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Scala [documentation for language features](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.language%24), explaining why implicit conversions have to be explicitly enabled in 2.10:

> **Why control it?** Implicit conversions are known to cause many pitfalls
>   if over-used. And there is a tendency to over-use them because they
>   look very powerful and their effects seem to be easy to understand.
>   Also, in most situations using implicit parameters leads to a better
>   design than implicit conversions.

User-defined implicit conversions are almost always a bad idea, and making them transitive would be much, much worse.

You can, however, use type classes to get a similar effect in a much safer, more controlled way. For example, suppose we have the following:

```
trait MyConverter[A, B] { def apply(a: A): B }

implicit def composeMyConverters[A, B, C](implicit
  ab: MyConverter[A, B],
  bc: MyConverter[B, C]
) = new MyConverter[A, C] { def apply(a: A) = bc(ab(a)) }
```

Now we can write:

```
implicit object doubleToString extends MyConverter[Double, String] {
  def apply(d: Double) = d.toString
}

implicit object intToDouble extends MyConverter[Int, Double] {
  def apply(i: Int) = i.toDouble
}

def convertToString[A](a: A)(implicit as: MyConverter[A, String]) = as(a)
```

And finally:

```
scala> convertToString(13: Int)
res0: String = 13.0
```

We've never explicitly defined a converter from integers to strings, but the compiler is able to use our `composeMyConverters` method to construct one when it's needed.

Like implicit conversions, this approach can also be abused, but it's much easier to keep tabs on what converters are in scope, where they're being applied, etc.

Comment: I like your approach Travis, but in effect youre chaining implicits making them transitive?

Comment: Yes, but the chaining happens automatically, and these aren't implicit conversions—they're type class instances that are conjured up by the compiler to satisfy implicit parameters.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that difference and why it is important?

Comment: There are implicit conversion all over the standard library, anyone can define more, and they can get applied in places you might not expect. In my example, you've defined the type class, so you know exactly what instances are available, and the conversion won't be applied automatically—you have to use the implicit parameter approach seen in my `convertToString` method.

Comment: Hey Travis, we just tried to do this for a longer chain (A -> B -> C -> D), and we're getting divergent derivations, which makes sense to us, because function composition is associative, so different groupings lead to multiple instances.  I doubt we can teach scalac about associativity, so I wonder if there's a way to avoid divergence.  Hopefully the answer isn't macros.